# combination of OPTIONAL CHAINING and NULLISH COALESCING operator not rendering the expected result

Tags: javascript, methods, optional-chaining, nullish-coalescing

i am just learning about this combo of **Optional chain** and **Nullish coalescing**.
Here is the `object`

```
const restaurant = {
name_: 'Classico Italiano',
location: 'Via Angelo Tavanti 23, Firenze, Italy',
categories: ['Italian', 'Pizzeria', 'Vegetarian', 'Organic'],
starterMenu: ['Focaccia', 'Bruschetta', 'Garlic Bread', 'Caprese Salad'],
mainMenu: ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Risotto'],

openingHours: {
    thu: {
        open: 12,
        close: 22,
    },
    fri: {
        open: 11,
        close: 23,
    },
    sat: {
        open: 0, // Open 24 hours
        close: 24,
    },
},
orderPizza(ing1, ing2) {
    console.log(`you have ordered your pizza with ${ing1} and ${ing2}`);
}};
```

as i am trying to check if the method exist,it is printing out both of them anyway.what am i doing wrong?

```
console.log(restaurant.orderPizza?.('some', 'something') ?? 'no method exist');
```

Comment: what do you like to print instead?

Comment: What **exactly** are you getting and what **exactly** are you expecting?

Comment: i am getting both of the value whereas i am supposed to get only the first one,if it exists or the last one,'No method exist',if it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps return a value from the function otherwise it has an undefined value:

```js
const restaurant1 = {
  name_: 'Classico Italiano',
  orderPizza(ing1, ing2) {
    return `you have ordered your pizza with ${ing1} and ${ing2}`;
  }
};

const restaurant2 = {
  name_: 'Other',
};

console.log(restaurant1.orderPizza?.('some', 'something') ?? 'no method exist');
console.log(restaurant2.orderPizza?.('some', 'something') ?? 'no method exist');
```

Comment: Yes,this solves the problem.but you see in another case,logging in the console works just fine.

Comment: @Nafi Are you able to return a non undefined or null value from the function regardless?